# Show that $-\frac{1}{i}=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In a proof I saw the following step $$\frac{V_x}{-i}=iV_x$$

It is obvious that $$\frac{V_x}{-i}\cdot\frac{i}{i}=iV_x$$

But shouldn't the $z\cdot \overline{z}=|z|^2$?  or in other words should not $-i\cdot i=(-1)^2+(1)^2=2$?

What am I missing here?

Comment: $i=0+1\cdot i$, and $\|i\|^2=(0+1\cdot i)\cdot(0-1\cdot i)=0^2+1^2$.

Comment: Multiply with $i$ to get $-1=i^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$-i\cdot i=-(i)^2=-(-1)=1$$
Also you say $z\cdot\bar z=|z|^2$, which is true - but $|z|=1$, as seen from an Argand diagram, or from the fact that $|z|:=\sqrt{Re(z)^2+Im(z)^2}=\sqrt{0^2+1^2}=1.$

Comment: Thanks, that what I was missing

Answer (score 4):

we have $$\frac{1}{-i}=\frac{-1}{i}\cdot \frac{i}{i}=\frac{-i}{i^2}=\frac{-i}{-1}=i$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Euler's formula $e^{\alpha i}=\cos{\alpha}+i\sin{\alpha}$:

$$\frac{1}{-i}=\frac{1}{e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}i}}=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=i$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $i^2 = -1$, squaring both sides gives $i^4 = 1$. Therefore:

$$-\frac{1}{i} = -i^3 = -i \times i^2 = -i \times -1 = i$$